# How to get random lines with a given distribution with awk?

Tags: awk

I have two tabular files that I want to merge, but prior to that I want to reduce the second one.

The first file let's say File1 is tabular and is like this

```
 A 67 98 56
 A 22 29 62
 A 11 99 28
 B 37 88 14
 B 33 99 65
```

We have 3 lines with A and two with B

File2 contains 3000 lines between A and B, I want to randomly select lines from File2 but exactly the same number of A and B than File1, which means just 3 random lines with A and two with B

Any one have an idea on how to do this with awk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r acount bcount <<< $(csplit file2 '/^B /')

awk -v "acount=$acount" -v "bcount=$bcount" '
    NR == FNR {
        arr[$1]++; 
        next
    }
    ! setup {
        setup = 1
        while (arandcount < acount) {
            line = int(rand() * acount) + 1
            if (! alines[line]) {
                alines[line] = 1
                arandcount++
            }
        }
        while (brandcount < bcount) {
            line = int(rand() * bcount) + 1
            if (! blines[line]) {
                blines[line] = 1
                brandcount++
            }
        }
    }
    FILENAME == "xx00" && FNR in alines {
        print
    }
    FILENAME == "xx01" && FNR in blines {
        print
    }' file1 xx00 xx01
```

Where "xx00" and "xx01" are the names of the files created by `csplit`.

The `csplit` command splits the input file on the regex and outputs the line counts of each output file. The `read` command puts those counts into the variables. The variables are passed into the AWK program.

The first block reads all the lines in file1 and counts each "type" (A or B).

The second block picks the line numbers to select by choosing a random number between 1 and the count of lines of the "type". This block only gets executed once because of the flag.

The last two blocks check each line's record number to see if it's in the array of picked line numbers and prints it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
grep '^A' file2 | sort -R | head -$(grep -c '^A' file1) >file3
grep '^B' file2 | sort -R | head -$(grep -c '^B' file1) >>file3
```

N.B. This assumes `file1` is sorted.